# jquery/javascript: adding an else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an else statement to this piece of javascript so that if a `div-1` is clicked once it shows `div-2` and if `div-1` is clicked again it hides `div-2`.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

```js
$(function() {
    $('.div-1').click(function() {
        $('.div-2').show();
        return false;
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Try [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead:

```
   $('.div-1').click(function() {
       $('.div-2').toggle();
       return false;
   });
```

Comment: thanks that works, is there also a way i could add in a statement to say when out of focus, also hide?

Comment: You could try the `blur` event. You could also add a click handler to the document that hides the div if blur doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dummy class and check for it's exixtence.

```
$(function() {
   $('.div-1').click(function() {
       var $this = $(this),
           $div2 = $('.div-2');
       if($this.hasClass('open')) {
            $this.removeClass(open');
            $div2.hide();
       } else {
            $this.addClass(open');
            $div2.show();
       }
       return false;
   });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Jason P's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414397/1366033) that you should be using [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead, but in case you actually *needed* to use an `if statement`, you can do this:

```js
$('.div-1').click(function() {
    if ($('.div-2').is(':visible')) {
        $('.div-2').hide();
    } else {
        $('.div-2').show();
    }
   return false;
});
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/7hMxF/)